# Thymeleaf th:field model evaluation

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm including dynamic content to a view using a custom Thymeleaf attribute processor that simply adds additional nodes while processing the attribute itself.

The code I use is very similar to the one below:

```
final Template template = arguments.getTemplateRepository().getTemplate(
            new TemplateProcessingParameters(arguments.getConfiguration(), "name-of-a-view", arguments.getContext()));
final List<Node> children = template.getDocument().getChildren();

// Add to the tree.
for (final Node node : children) {
    element.addChild(node);
}
```

This works fine, but breaks when the included nodes contains forms that use th:object and th:field.

I put the model I need inside the node variable map and in fact th:object does find and retrieves the object, but th:field does not seems to care and breaks with a

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'model' available as request attribute
```

From my understanding (step-by-step debugging), it seems to me that th:field only search for the model in the request context.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're spot on. I'm still not sure why the binding is different for th:field than other th: attributes, but it definitely works differently.  Essentially, you can't use th:field unless your th:object is on the model. The workaround is to stop using th:field and just specify your input attributes manually, like:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/process}" th:object="${objectFromList}" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="fieldName" name="fieldName" th:value="*{fieldName}" />   
</form>
```

I realize this post is old.  Hopefully, this will help someone who is running into this quirk.